# EXCEL: How to get the specific value from a Table directly, with out using INDEX

Tags: excel-2016

I know this question maybe duplicated, but sorry guys I really tried a lot and cannot figure out the answer.

Say I have a Table in excel called MyDataTable How to get the value from row 2 and a column named Column1? What is the right way? I don't want to use INDEX.

I have tried

- =MyDataTable[[@],[Column1]]
- =MyDataTable[2,[Column1]]
- =MyDataTable[[2],[Column1]]
- =MyDataTable[[#This Row],[Column1]]
- =MyDataTable[[2],[6]]
- =[MyDataTable].Cells(2,6)
- ...

None of them work. I am totally stuck. I think it should be a easy question but... shamed to ask.

BTW, I am trying to get the value from the table directly, not anything like F3, $F$3, ...

New findings....

If I type in
**=MyDataTable[Column1]** directly, and the cell is on the row of the table which I want to get data from, it will get the value. However, how can I change the rownumber?

Say if MyDataTable row 2 Column1 has value 10, if I typed =MyDataTable[Column1] on any sheet row 2, I will get 10. But if I move the cell to a different row, it won't work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

`=MyDataTable[@1]`

If you're trying to get A1 in my MyDataTable for instance, you will do this in the same row in say something like Z1. Keep it on the same row or it will display `#VALUE` instead or the wrong row's data.

Comment: Yes I mentioned in my question that, it will work if on the same row. do you know how can I make it work on different row?